# Null Value Exception when Retrieving Blob Storage Account

Tags: .net, azure, blob

In my program, I have multiple points where it connects to Blob storage to read/write files. They all work fine. However, in a different function but the same class as where another Blob storage reference is made, I am getting an ArgumentNullException stating "Value cannot be null" from the following line of code:

```
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
```

I know the StorageConnectionString is properly configured, because when I remove the line of code using this function, the same line of code works in other functions. Can anyone provide some insight as to why this one function is causing a problem, but not the others?

Not sure if this would be too helpful, but here's the 4 lines of code I'm using. It's pretty standard.

```
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
CloudBlobClient client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference(CONTAINER);
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(FilePath(null, imageId));
```

Comment: Could you give an example of your connection string (without the actual key)? And are all of your functions, the ones that work and the one that doesn't work, running in the same process (ie: an application pool in your Web Role)?

Comment: The connection string is under <appSettings> as follows:
    <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http; AccountName=[Name]; AccountKey=[KEY]" />

The functions that work are in the same process and web role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment this could be related to the fact that you store the connection string in the web.config. In some cases it might look like your code is running in the same process, but in reality it isn't. Take the **WebRole.cs/WorkerRole.cs** classes for example. Simply put, the code in these classes will run in a different process, which means they won't have access to your web.config. The WebRole.cs will read its settings from the **WaIISHost.exe.config** file for example.

Could you remove the connection string from the web.config and add it to the service configuration instead? You don't need to modify the code since the `CloudConfigurationManager` will look in the service configuration first, and if it doesn't find the setting here it will fall back to the web/app.config

[image]

**Note:** In this answer I'm assuming you are using a Web Role and not a Web Site.

Comment: This was exactly the issue. The function that it worked in was being called from the WebRole and the one where it didn't work was being called by the WorkerRole. I've added the StorageConnectionString to the service configuration of the WorkerRole and the issue has been solved. Thank you so much!